# Save Image Issue in .net Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using following code for Crowling image.

I am deleting images which is already exists.

It is working but when I am saving new Image then it is saving image but the created file time shows same as previous created file time.

can anyone know how could I solve this issue ?

my code is as below.

```
Image _Image = DownloadImage(ImageSrc);
if (_Image != null)
{
    if (File.Exists(LargeImagePath + FileName))
    {
        File.Delete(LargeImagePath + FileName);
    }   
    _Image.Save(LargeImagePath + FileName);
}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but here's why it is happening: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is the best solution but you could always manually set the file's creation date:

```
File.SetCreationTime(LargeImagePath + FileName, DateTime.Now);
```